# Can't open SQL 2005 Express database from solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

We are having a problem with Visual Studio 2008 Professional, where opening a SQL express database from Solution explorer only opens the file in binary form.

We thought that the wrong application might be set, but using open with and selecting SQL express bootstrapper still yields the same result.

We can open the database file if we use the server explorer data connections window and connect to the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you precisely want to do?
If you want to see your database, the tables & SPs then use SQL Management Studio for that: http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

Well as far as I know you can't view the database in the solution explorer.

Use the server explorer or SQL Server Management Studio Express.

If you have a mdf file you want to include into your project, place it into the App_Data folder.

[Using SQL Server Express Edition with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx)